# How do I use jQuery from windows using webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I have a node module in which some of the components use jQuery but the node module doesn't have a package.json file in it, so every dependency I have to provide it using the package.json of my project. One the file in node module uses `jQuery` from the `window` so I have to provide some functionality so that it can use it from there. I tried making a shims file and then used ProvidePlugin in webpack as :

```
module.exports = {
  shimloaders: [
    //{test: /modernizr/, loader: 'exports?Modernizr'},
    {test: /jquery$/, loader: 'exports?$,jQuery'},
    {test: /jquery.ui$/, loader: 'exports?$.ui!imports?jquery'},
    {test: /backbone$/, loader: 'imports?jquery,lodash-dep'},
    {test: /jqContextualDialog$/, loader: 'imports?jquery,lodash-dep'},
    {test: /backbone.marionette$/, loader: 'imports?jquery,lodash-dep,backbone'},
    {test: /jquery.imagesLoaded/, loader: 'imports?jquery'},
    {test: /jquery.imageViewer/, loader: 'imports?jquery'},
    {test: /planner-application$/, loader: 'imports?jquery,modernizr,lodash-dep,backbone'},
  ],
  shims: {
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    'window.$': 'jquery',
    'root.jQuery': 'jquery'
  }
};
```

in my webpack config files as:

```
plugins: [
    new ProvidePlugin(shims)
]
```

and pushed the `shimloaders` in the webpack loaders.

but it didn't work.

Second thing I tried is in the entry file of my product, I used :

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

but it still didn't work.

What is the best method to pass jQuery in my window, so that my node module can use it?

Is there some other work around where I can use that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader).

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: require.resolve("jQuery"), loader: "expose-loader?jQuery" }
  ]
}
```